# What is the proper way to unregister Activity lifecycle callbacks?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

In the Android Application class you can register/unregister [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html), which allow you to monitor Activity lifecycle events in your application all in one place (if you so desire).

Where is the proper place to call [unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29)? I'm registering in [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29), and was thinking that onTerminate would be the proper place just from the name of the method but the docs say for **onTerminate()**:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never
>   be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed
>   by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is
>   executed when doing so.

I don't see any other methods in the Application class where a 'shutdown' type callback is made. Do you even need to unregister?

Comment: I'm really curious as to what you're trying to achieve.  Regarding unregister, you wouldn't need to since if your Application class is dying, your process is dying so you would unregister, presumably after the super() call, a few microseconds before your process dies.  I guess that the purpose of unregister is to enable you to change behaviours at run time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789657/simon) was right about this. `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` doesn't require a matching call to `unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. As described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479979/action-on-application-killed-in-android) you can't detected when your application is being killed. So there is no "logical" place to unregister your callback. And even if there was, your `Application` instance is killed **after** the last `Activity` action takes place, and the killing of your `Application` kills the `mActivityLifecycleCallbacks` list which holds the reference to your callback anyway.

TL;DR - Don't worry about calling `unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, it's only there if you want to stop tracking `Activity` actions during your `Application`'s normal lifecycle.